# Why is cookie not being attached to request?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I have the following cookie set during a login call (`https://localhost.company.com:4430/login`):

```
Name=COMPANY.AUTH
Value=<an encoded value>
Domain=.company.com
Path=/
Expires=<well in the future>
HttpOnly=true
Secure=false
SameSite=Lax
SameParty=<not set>
Priority=Medium
```

When I instigate an HTTP request to `https://api-localhost.company.com/some-api` in either Chrome 90 or Firefox 88, the cookie is not attached.

I cannot understand why. Moreover, Chrome does not show the Cookies tab against the request, which is supposedly able to help diagnose why cookies are not being attached.

Can anyone tell me why the above wouldn't work?